# Consuming a WCF Service Hosted in ASP.NET Website

Tags: wcf

I got a WCF service which had been hosted within a ASP.NET Web Site. The service is only available if somebody login into that Website.The WCF Service uses webHttp binding. Now I got an requirement to consume the Service   from a Console Application from some other M/c. I have the authentication credentials (username/password) for login into the website.Is there anyway by which I can consume the Service from the Console Application using credentials? As a precondition I cannot change anything in the Service side.

Comment: Does any part of your WCF services implementation use `System.Web.HttpContext` (traditional web session)?  And are you using ASP.NET forms authentication?  If so, then the console app will need to mimic a web browser and reflect back a cookie on all WCF requests.  I can provide some code to illustrate, if this is the case.  The symptoms will be, the Console will login successfully with good auth, but will fail on other WCF requests because the server-side is getting a null `HttpContext`.

Comment: Hi, You are correct. The Website is using Form Authentication. In my case I cannot call the service using credentials. My understanding is that,as the Website is using Form Authentication, we need the Cookie information in addition to the credentials. But, I dont have any idea, how I can get Cookie information that had been used by the Website. Please provide some code as you said.

Answer (score 0):

This technique worked for me because the code behind in the page using forms authentication was calling our WCF service to do the actual login processing, i.e. we had an `OperationContract` already made.

```
    string address = "http://localhost:4567";
    var serviceClient = new SomeService.MyServiceClient(
        "BasicHttpBinding_IMyService", address + "/myservice.svc");

    // Call the service login method, save off the response's cookie(s)
    string cookiesFromLogin = string.Empty;
    bool logonSucceeded = false;
    using (new OperationContextScope(serviceClient.InnerChannel))
    {
        logonSucceeded = serviceClient.DoTheLogin("userName", "userPass");

        var httpResponse = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)
            OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties[
                HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];
        cookiesFromLogin = httpResponse.Headers["Set-Cookie"];
    }

    // Then later when you need to make other service calls, insert the cookie(s)
    // into the request headers
    using (new OperationContextScope(serviceClient.InnerChannel))
    {
        var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        httpRequest.Headers["Cookie"] = cookiesFromLogin;
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[
            HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequest;

        var someResults = serviceClient.CallSomeMethod("param1");
    }
```